# What does this gSoap fault message mean?

Tags: gsoap

I am using gSoap to communicate with the web service. I am using Qt to create application that uses gSoap. I am getting following fault message for some of the calls

**SOAP 1.1 fault: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher":DeserializationFailed[no subcode]
"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetPendingCommands'. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: Body, Envelope. Line 2, position 459.**"

Can someone please explain me what could be wrong with the service?

Thanks

DPatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If chunking is turned on in your client side code, try turning it off.  I seem to recall that you have to do something special with gSoap to get it to support chunking on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means the client has received a truncated SOAP envelope. This often happens if the web service neglects to flush its output buffer before returning.